# OCMock failures "Another mock is already associated with object" with XCTest in XCode 7

Tags: xctest, ocmock

I just upgraded to XCode 7 recently, forcing me to upgrade OCMock so that I have support for x64 architectures.  Apparently a change was made in OCMock which does not allow for a previously mocked object to be remocked-- in other words, I had a helper method that did something like this:

```
-(MyObject *)getObject {
    Factory *factory = [self.dependencyInjector getInstance:factory];
    id mockFactory = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:factory];
    [[[mockFactory stub] andReturn:@"important-value"] thing];
    return [[MYObject alloc] initWithFactory:mockFactory];
}
```

This worked fine previously, but apparently there was a change to OCMockObject to not allow a re-mocking of an already mocked object.  Since the factory object returned by the injector is effectively a singleton, subsequent calls to the getObject method is calling partialMockForObject: on it multiple times and this now throws an exception "Another mock is already associated with object".

Is there any way to make OCMock not throw an error?  I tried calling stopMocking on the object prior to mocking it, but that does not fix this issue.  The only way around it was to do something like:

```
-(MyObject *)getObject {
    if (!self.mockFactory) {
        Factory *factory = [self.dependencyInjector getInstance:factory];
        id mockFactory = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:factory];
        [[[mockFactory stub] andReturn:@"important-value"] thing];
        self.mockFactory = mockFactory;
    }
    return [[MYObject alloc] initWithFactory:self.mockFactory];
}
```

which is really annoying to have to do...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code as it is today, the implementation of `stopMocking` explicitly resets the associated object (https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/dd5599695dcc50afe4d6bdff509ed3cbe389c667/Source/OCMock/OCPartialMockObject.m#L80). I'm at a loss how calling `stopMocking` doesn't solve the problem. Can you build a debug version of OCMock and set a breakpoint at the line highlighted above and see whether it's called?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it turned out to be a race condition.

The mock was instantiated using a common factory that was injected into a class under test. The class under test performed some action and then called the factory to create the mock object on a global queue without any consistent thread specified.

The solution I went with was to create a static instance of the mocked object and reuse it throughout my tests.